# Write SQL query that picks all rows except the ones that have specified value in three columns at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 columns -- GroupingKey, GroupingValue and GroupingType in a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Grouping
    (`GroupingKey` varchar(8), `GroupingValue` varchar(7), `GroupingType` varchar(8));

INSERT INTO Grouping
    (`GroupingKey`, `GroupingValue`, `GroupingType`)
VALUES
    ('Language', 'Italian', 'Category'),
    ('Language', 'Russian', 'Unknown'),
    ('Unknown', 'Unknown', 'Unknown'),
    ('Phone', 'Unknown', 'Unknown');
```

What would be the SQL query to select all rows in the above table except the row that has Unknown, Unknown, Unknown in GroupingKey, GroupingValue and GroupingType respectively?

My expected output of the SQL query is:

| GroupingKey | GroupingValue | GroupingType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Language | Italian | Category |
| Language | Russian | Unknown |
| Phone | Unknown | Unknown |

I tried writing a query as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT groupingkey,
                groupingvalue,
                groupingtype
FROM   mytablename
WHERE  groupingkey NOT LIKE 'Unknown'
       AND groupingvalue NOT LIKE 'Unknown'
       AND groupingtype NOT LIKE 'Unknown'
```

But what is ending up happening is that it does not pick any row that has "Unknown" even in 1 of the 3 columns specified above

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for your reply, were you referring to just how the query was formatted? Because I feel I have provided the relevant tables and what query I tried executing as specified in the link you provided. Thanks

Comment: Your query says AND groupingkey... AND...groupingvalue AND... groupingtype.... So only if all are like 'Unkknown'.  Myabe you should change `AND` to `OR` ?

Comment: E.g.: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4vRJcLtcNguS18xyjwv5AV/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the condition like this:

```
WHERE NOT (
            groupingkey = 'Unknown'
        AND groupingvalue = 'Unknown'
        AND groupingtype = 'Unknown'
          )
```

Note that for your requirement you should use `=` instead of `LIKE`.

Or:

```
WHERE groupingkey <> 'Unknown'
   OR groupingvalue <> 'Unknown'
   OR groupingtype <> 'Unknown'
```

which means that at least 1 of the columns must not be `'Unknown'`.

Or:

```
WHERE (groupingkey, groupingvalue, groupingtype) <> ('Unknown', 'Unknown', 'Unknown')
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0b707d863975bd14f46f0bfeba2eedee).